# find number range in java

Tags: java

How to get number range in java? for instance how can verify is the number 2389 within 10 numbers from 2400. its not but 2389 is.

Ok here is the rephrase :

Number 1000 is the range number 990 is comming in the loop, I return true because the between 990 and 1000 is 10 numbers diference.

In comes the next number 989 range is always 1000, I return false because the between 989 and 1000 is 11 numbers diference.

In comes the next number 1013 range is always 1000, I return false because the between 1013 and 1000 is 13 numbers diference.

Comment: is 2389 plus/minus 10 larger/smaller/equal to 2400 - should be easy to translate to java. Or is the difference between 2400 and 2389 more than +/- 10 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use absolute values and `Math.abs(num1-num2) <= 10`

Comment: Careful: Math.abs(Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE) == 1

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isWithinRange(int number, int around, int range){
    int difference = Math.abs(around - number);
    return difference <= range;
}
```

Comment: @Gandalf: it returns the absolute value of the number.  So the question really is, what is the absolute value of a number?  In simple terms it is the number in positive form (if the number is already positive then it is the same value, if it is negative then it is negated so that it is positive), e.g. abs(5) == 5, abs(-123) == 123